# Disabling Registration in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, authentication

After disabling registration in laravel 5.8, logout route no longer works

I replaced

```
Auth::routes();
```

in web.php with

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

My web.php file:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

//Auth::routes();

Auth::routes(['register' => false]);

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
```

The registration link goes away but I get a 500 server error when I attempt to log out at /logout page.

Comment: Can you run `php artisan route:list` to check if the logout route is there.

Comment: |        | POST     | logout                                                       | logout            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web                                       |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                                                       |                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web,auth

Comment: without disable registration page, you can redirect registration page to login page or home page

Comment: Can you paste the code of how you put the logout button in the blade file

Comment: A 500 error should have a log entry along with a stack trace that might help

Answer (score 1):

I've had that problem myself, you can manually add the route.

Under

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

place

```
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout' );
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating your web.php

Run

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Comment: Clearing the route cache doesn't help. If I hit the back button from the error page  and log out again it works. Same thing happens logging in.

Comment: Are you currently login to a page before you click the logout button?

Comment: Yes I am logged in and on the main page of the app.

Comment: @gildedpage Did you add middleware in your main page controller?

try adding 
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
} in your controller